# .xinitrc doesn't run script when using startx

Tags: python, bash, xorg

I have made a file .xinitrc in the users home directory. In the file I've put

`exec python3 /srv/Game/main.py`

But the python script doesn't run when launching x with

`startx`

What am I doing wrong? I thoght this was how you used .xinitrc

Comment: Do you config the permissions? If not, run chmod u+x ~/.xinitrc

Comment: first you could add `echo "Hello World" > output.txt` to see if it really execute this file.

Comment: "doesn't run" -- how do you determine that? What potential factors have you ruled out, like e.g. python, the location of the program, PATH env, permissions?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions everyone. It seemed like it was permissions which caused it. Im quite grateful for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, and it was mostly issued with permissions in both the directory for the python file and for .xinitrc. Used `chmod -R` to solve it. Thank you for the suggestions.